# SOQL query doesn't retrieve all contacts

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am working on a code snippet that is supposed to import all my contacts from Salesforce via SOQL.

Here is what I do when I want to import all Salesforce contacts for my user 00520000001IbXZAA0

First SOQL:

```
SELECT Id FROM account WHERE ownerid = ‘00520000001IbXZAA0’
```

Then I get all the account id where I am a team member:

```
SELECT AccountId FROM accountteammember WHERE UserId = ‘00520000001IbXZAA0’
```

Then I build an array with my ids and from my 2 previous requests and get all contacts this way:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN myarrayofids ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
```

This approach seems to get most of my contacts but I can still see some contacts appear in Salesforce but that are not retrieved with these 3 queries. Am I missing something here?

I have only very few knowledge of how Salesforce work but I suppose that if I retrieve all contacts where I am a team member or owner, I should retrieve all contacts I am able to see on Salesforce or am I missing something here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to see all records otherwise is as some might be shared with you via OWD or using role based sharing, manual sharing or apex sharing. If you are just looking for a list in csv or anything, the easiest thing you can do here is create a report to display all contacts and share it with this user. Login into Salesforce as this "00520000001IbXZAA0" user. Run the report and export into csv/excel.
If you wish to do this in code, write a class using "with sharing" keyword and run the following query "Select Id, FirstName, LastName .... From Contact". This will return this user all the records she/he has access to.

Try these above solutions and let me know if they work for you. Happy to help..!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see your point with the role based sharing, and I confirm that the sharing of contacts and account is private and the sharing rules are based on role with specific rules.

But the point I cannot understand is that the SOQL is ran with the User login. It should return what the user is allowed to see and modify. And the problem is that for the three missing contacts, all three contacts are owned by the user and belong to accounts owned by the user.

So it shouldn't be a role based limitation it seems...

Comment: I suggest check user's access using below query:
SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
     FROM UserRecordAccess
     WHERE UserId = [single ID]
     AND RecordId = [single ID]      //or Record IN [list of IDs]
This will give you better insights. If not able to crack this, post query result here, will provide more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Here is the response for your query:

{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"UserRecordAccess","url":"\/services\/data\/v33.0\/sobjects\/UserRecordAccess\/0035700001yZvAYAA0"},"RecordId":"0035700001yZvAYAA0","HasReadAccess":true,"HasTransferAccess":true,"MaxAccessLevel":"All"}]}

Any idea?

Comment: This is interesting. Any chance we connect on skype to share screen to debug this?